# getTickCount time unit confusion

Tags: opencv

At the answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031357/opencv-mat-processing-time/13187332#13187332) on Stack and in the book at [here on page 52](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=opencv%20cookbook%20pdf&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://lecture7.tistory.com/attachment/cfile24.uf@15094C4E512B0E4920B7B2.pdf&ei=AiGBUdzaM8TKrAed8oHIBA&usg=AFQjCNGpR1lRxZeLWX7XACC9_6th1n--aQ&bvm=bv.45921128,d.bmk) I found the normal getTickCount getTickFrequency combination to measure time of execution gives time in milliseconds . However the [OpenCV website](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#cv-gettickcount) says its time in seconds. I am confused. Please help...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no room for confusion, all the references you have given point to the same thing.

`getTickCount` gives you the **number of clock cycles** after a certain event, eg, after machine is switched on.

```
A = getTickCount()  // A = no. of clock cycles from beginning, say 100
process(image)      // do whatever process you want
B = getTickCount()  // B = no. of clock cycles from beginning, say 150

C = B - A           // C = no. of clock cycles for processing, 150-100 = 50,
                    // it is obvious, right?
```

Now you want to know how many seconds are these clock cycles. For that, you want to know how many seconds a single clock takes, ie **clock_time_period**. If you find that, simply multiply by 50 to get total time taken.

For that, OpenCV gives second function, `getTickFrequency()`. It gives you **frequency**, ie **how many clock cycles per second**. You take its reciprocal to get time period of clock.

```
time_period = 1/frequency.
```

Now you have **time_period** of one clock cycle, multiply it with 50 to get total time taken in seconds.

Now read all those references you have given once again, you will get it.

Answer (score -1):

```
dwStartTimer=GetTickCount();
dwEndTimer=GetTickCount();
            while((dwEndTimer-dwStartTimer)<wDelay)//delay is 5000 milli seconds
            {
                Sleep(200);
                dwEndTimer=GetTickCount();
                if (PeekMessage (&uMsg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) 
                 {
                     TranslateMessage (&uMsg);
                     DispatchMessage (&uMsg);
                 }
            }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting only code is often not very helpful.

Comment: This question is about OpenCV `getTickCount` function, not `GetTickCount` of Win32 API.