# Speeding up HoughCircles

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, hough-transform

I have problem with the houghcircles function, regarding its processing speed. when i try to run the code with this video file, i uploaded onto Youtube. https://youtu.be/5RGRTPEdHVY

The problem is, when the copter is taking off, the code is stucked, and stop moving. At this stage, when the copter is taking off, the param must be set manually at 300 to avoid being stucked. then after taking off, the param must be reduced to about 150 or 130 to detect the circles on the field.

Now i do not want to do it manually, is there a way to do it intelligently?

Or is there any way to ensure the video is smooth?
are my parameters too small? And what is the unit for these parameters?

Also i wish to know if it is the Hough Circle that is slowing things down or the drawing of the circles?

Thank you

Full Code is attached.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "tserial.h"
#include "bot_control.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    //Create a window for trackbars
    namedWindow("Trackbar Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    //Create trackbar to change brightness
    int iSliderValue1 = 50;
    createTrackbar("Brightness", "Trackbar Window", &iSliderValue1, 100);

    //Create trackbar to change contrast
    int iSliderValue2 = 50;
    createTrackbar("Contrast", "Trackbar Window", &iSliderValue2, 100);

    //Create trackbar to change param1 in HoughCircle
    int param1 = 300;
    createTrackbar("param1", "Trackbar Window", &param1, 300);

    //Create trackbar to change param2 in HoughCircle
    int param2 = 300;
    createTrackbar("param2", "Trackbar Window", &param2, 300);

    //Create trackbar to change min Radius in HoughCircle
    int minR = 0;
    createTrackbar("minRadius", "Trackbar Window", &minR, 300);

    //Create trackbar to change max Radius in HoughCircle
    int maxR = 0;
    createTrackbar("maxRadius", "Trackbar Window", &maxR, 300);

    //Debugging purpose
    cout << "All trackbars created" << endl;

    int iBrightness;
    double dContrast;

    double dparam1;
    double dparam2;

    time_t start, end;
    int counter = 0;

    ofstream myfile;

    serial comm;
    char data = 1;

    comm.startDevice("COM3", 9600);

    time(&start);   
    //Create a variable to store image
    Mat src;
    //Create video capture
    VideoCapture capture;
    //open video from either a file or webcam

    capture.open("C:\\Users\\Student-ID\\Downloads\\GOPR0506.MP4");
    //capture.open(0);



    //set frame height
    //capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120);
    //capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 120);

    //Set the capture FPS
    //capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,25);

    //store whatever is captured to src
    capture.read(src);

    //Debugging purpose
    cout << "Vidoe opened" << endl;

    if (!src.data) {
        std::cout << "ERROR:\topening image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //Create window to display videos
    cv::namedWindow("image1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    while (true){

        capture.read(src);
        //Code for changing Brightness and contrast
        iBrightness = iSliderValue1 - 50;
        dContrast = iSliderValue2 / 50.0;
        src.convertTo(src, -1, dContrast, iBrightness);

        //Debugging purpose
        //cout << "1" << endl;


        //Create variable to store the processed image
        Mat src_gray2;
        //Convert the colour to grayscale
        cvtColor(src, src_gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        //Smooth and blur the image to reduce noise
        GaussianBlur(src_gray2, src_gray2, cv::Size(9, 9), 2, 2);





        //Change the param1 and 2 to double from integer
        dparam1 = param1 / 1.0;
        dparam2 = param2 / 1.0;

        //Debugging purpose
        cout << "2" << endl;

        //Apply HoughCircle function
        HoughCircles(src_gray2, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
        2,   // accumulator resolution (size of the image / 2)
        5,  // minimum distance between two circles
        dparam1, // Canny high threshold
        dparam2, // minimum number of votes
        minR, maxR); // min and max radius

        //Debugging purpose
        cout << "3" << endl;

        cout << "size of circle is: "<< circles.size() << endl;


        if (circles.size() != 0){
            //Draw the circle
            for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
            {
                Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
                int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
                circle(src, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);
                // circle outline
                circle(src, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
                //Display words on top left hand corner
                putText(src, "Circle Found", Point(0, 50), 1, 2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

                comm.send_data(data);
            }



        }



        //display video

        imshow("image1", src);

        //debugging purpose
        cout << "5" << endl;

        //delay to refresh the pic
        int key = cvWaitKey(33);
        if (key == 27) break;

        time(&end);
        ++counter;
        cout << "fps is: " << counter / difftime(end, start) << endl << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I tried limiting the number of circles being drawn suggested by Miki (Thank you).
The frame still stops at take off, although it is only drawing 2 circles and maybe 5 circles on the next frame.

Please do comment if you have some methods in mind.

Comment: Maybe instead of performing hough circles on the entire image, you could first perform some less expensive operation to find a region of interest, like finding a bright spot in the image (as your white circle appears to be)

Comment: sorry. it won't be allowed. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I struggle to see why your professor should see it as a breach in the assignment (as long you still do hough in the ROI you find through processing). You can set min and max circle radius to see if this improves performance. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html To know which parts consume more time you need to add timers, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16322327/2436175). If you do that, remove the couts. Also, `dparam1 = param1 / 1.0;` should be `dparam1 = (double) param1;` :)

Comment: Drawing is slowing things down for sure. But how about profiling your code to find out the bottlenecks?

Comment: Hi thank you all for your response. Is there a way to limit the number of circles being drawn even a lot are being detected?

my `cout` tells me that it is stuck between 2 and 3, so is detecting part slowing down too because there are too many circles?

Comment: `size_t max_circles = min(10, circles.size()); for(size_t i=0; i<max_circles; ++i) {//etc...}`

Comment: Hi, I further reduced the number for the `min` to 5, the video is still stucked at the same place as before. Looks like the drawing is not the problem. It is with the `HoughCircles`
I can't really use the radius parameters, as the copter is not able to maintain a level flight, it goes up and down sometimes and thus change the size of the circles seen by the camera. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recently use Houghcircle function. I have a little experience. You declare circles(variable) that is global variable, and if you move copter but HoughCircle fcn haven't found the circle yet. It will remain circles values (center(x,y),radius) in the past, so the image looks like some latency. You can write about Hough's program as a subroutine. vector circles variable that is local variable in this subroutine. May improve latency.