# opencv Houghcircles detection

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, hough-transform

For the function of `HoughCircles` I have my code written this way

```
//Debugging purpose
        cout << "2" << endl;

        //Apply HoughCircle function

        HoughCircles(src_gray2, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
        2,   // accumulator resolution (size of the image / 2)
        5,  // minimum distance between two circles
        dparam1, // Canny high threshold
        dparam2, // minimum number of votes
        minR, maxR); // min and max radius

        //Debugging purpose
        cout << "3" << endl;
```

The dparam1 dparam2 minR and MaxR are slider bars.
After this code, is the standard way of drawing the circle on the ROI.

When running the code, the code always stops between 2 and 3. Also i limited the number of circles being drawn to 5 to prevent overloading.

Now the problem is that the code is slow and hang because of this part. So is there a way to speed up this thing, or limit the number of circles being DETECTED?
I only have one circle to detect at a time.

NOTE: The dparam1 and 2 are set to around 160
minR and max R are set to 0 as size of circles are unknown.

Thank you

Comment: "the code always stops" does it freeze or does it just take some time? What's your image size? Is there always a circle in the image? Can you post a sample image?

Comment: you could try a RANSAC based circle detection.

Comment: Hi, most of the time: screen freeze and code take at least 10 seconds to move on to another loop. Sometimes the program hang..

Circle is only drawn if it is detected, detection part is no problem
image size is uncontrollable because it is from a video file, you can read the link i attached. 
please refer to this linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120603/speeding-up-houghcircles?noredirect=1#comment54059328_33120603

Comment: what kind of hardware platform is used to process the code? HoughCircles isn't very fast. If there's no bug and it just needs 10 seconds to compute on that hardware, I don't see a chance to use it ;) but it doesnt look like houghCircles would be perfect at all. You want to detect those white marker circles (which are distorted to something not-circle anymore because of the lens if not in the center of the image)?

Comment: if the params are kept at 160+- it is still able to detect the circular object. It is done on an I7 core laptop with 8GB RAM, 2.9GHz CPU speed and 64 bit OS. Why is it taking so long to process, if 1 or 2 seconds delay, i still can accept. However, it is taking 10 seconds to process one frame .

Comment: can you please try to extract single frames and measure time only to process these? I don't think your processing should be that slow.

Comment: e.g. write a small program that saves each image to a different filename (.png) with `cv::imwrite(filename,capturedImage);`